# WPF: DataGrid with blanck cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to make an app that enables users to enter information into a `DataGrid`, I am doing this in the code behind. This is a portion of the code I am using:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
{
    collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    //Create a new tab and a new grid to fill the tab number i
    TabItem classTab = new TabItem();
    DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();

    dataGrid.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Times New Roman");
    dataGrid.FontSize = 18;
    dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = true;


    dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
    {
        Width = 800,
        Header = "الفوج أ" 
    });


    if(i == 8)
    {
        classTab.Header = "القسم الثانوي";
    }
    else
    {
        if (i == 7)
        {
            classTab.Header = "القسم الإعدادي";
        }
        else
        {
            classTab.Header = "القسم"  + "  " + i.ToString();
        }

    }

    dataGrid.ItemsSource = collection;
    classTab.Content = dataGrid;

    //Insert class tab into classes 
    classes.Items.Add(classTab);
}
```

collection has already been declared, also the `TabItems` are properly inserted into a `TabControl`.

For some reason this does not result in giving me what I want (a blank chart). it gives me the column I created plus another column with a Header named Length.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [`DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) Property to `false`

Comment: Okey, the extra column is removed, thanks. But what about the chart?